# Best way to optimize a pandas dataframe indexing to elastic

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, elasticsearch

I have a dataframe with over a million lines of data. I want to save it to elasticsearch using bulk.

This is my approach so far

```
from elasticsearch import helpers
import pandas as pd
def save_views(self, df_views):
    es = self.es
    bulk_data = []
    df_views['update_time'] = datetime.now()
    df_dicts = df_views.to_dict(orient='records')
    for doc in df_dicts:
        doc_id = str(doc['date']) + "_" + doc['name']
        action = {"_id" : doc_id, "_index" : my_index, "_type" : my_type, "_source" : doc}
        bulk_data.append(action)
    try:
        helpers.bulk(es, bulk_data, stats_only=False)
        self.logger.info ("Views saved!")
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.error(str(e))
```

It works on my testing environment, however, it consumes a lot of ram memory on the process, and my server is not handling it.

Is there a better way to create this bulk_data list?

Comment: Try reading this doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html or you could also use a small performance enhance by using df['colum'].values when the index is not needed. This saves memory and time.

Comment: You have a dataframe with over a million lines of data, Elasticsearch need an important memory to deal with your data. Try to run your script without the last part `helpers.bulk` and check if your script use huge memory or it's due to elasticsearch